# How to get a reference to LocationManager inside a Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, locationmanager

I have a class that extends Fragment and implements LocationListener.
When I write

```
LocationManager myLocalManager =
(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

I get an compile time error because the method `getSystemService` is not a method of Fragment.

What can I do in order to create the `LocationManager`?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

inside your fragment simply call this:

```
LocationManager mgr = 
(LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

So you simply get the Activity and call `getSystemService()` from there

**Edit:**
As the `getActivity` method is deprecated since API 28 you can just use:

```
LocationManager mgr = 
    (LocationManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: thank you, I was close but couldn't get it just the right way

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet it will work.

**Code :**

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```